# Java Polymorphism behaviour

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

I have written a code where every machine object has an id auto generated using a static field 'id'. I am trying to understand polymorphism in JAVA. The expected output is 1 2 3 4 but the output I am getting is is 1 2 4 6. Could anybody explain why this is happening?

```
class Machine{
    static int id=1;
    private int mach_id;
    private String name;
    Machine(){
        this.mach_id = id;
        id++;
    }
    public int getId(){
        return this.mach_id;
    }

}

class Camera extends Machine {
    private int mach_id;
    Camera(){
        this.mach_id = id;
        id++;
    }

}


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Machine mach = new Machine();
        Camera cam = new Camera();
        Machine mach1 = new Camera();
        Machine mach2 = new Camera();
        System.out.println(mach.getId());
        System.out.println(cam.getId());
        System.out.println(mach1.getId());
        System.out.println(mach2.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're double incrementing the id, once in the Machine constructor and once in the Camera constructor. Your camera classes doesn't need mach_id field, Machine should provide a getter for its value. Try adding a System.out.println to your constructors and see the workflow...

Comment: Ok. But what I fail to understand is when I am creating a Camera Object it is not incremented by two.  i.e, when I created Camera cam = new Camera() it was only incremented by one. So when I am creating a Machine object using new Camera() I am actually calling the Camera constructor only. So in this case why does it increment by 2. I know I might be sounding naive but I am new to OOPs so please bear with me.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what happens:

```
Machine mach = new Machine();
```

The `Machine` constructor is called directly. `id` is currently `1`. So it gives the new object the `mach_id` of `1`, and `id` is incremented.

```
Camera cam = new Camera();
```

The `Camera` constructor is called directly.

The first thing any constructor does is call the constructor of the superclass. If you didn't tell it to do so explicitly, it will implicitly call the no-arg constructor of the superclass. So now the `Machine` constructor is called.

It sets the value of `mach_id` of this object (viewing it as a `Machine` to the current value of `id`, which is 2. It then increments `id`.

Now the `Camera` constructor begins its own work. It takes the current value of `id`, which is currently `3`, puts it in `mach_id`, and increments `id`. It is now `4`.

Now here is the tricky part. The `mach_id` in `Camera` is hiding the `mach_id` in `Machine`. But the method `getID()` in `Machine` doesn't see the `mach_id` defined in `Camera`. It sees the one in `Machine`. So when you call it, it gets the value from the call to the supeclass constructor, which is 2. It doesn't see the private field that you created in `Camera` and has no knowledge of its value, which is `3`.

And then you construct new `Camera` objects again. You put them in `Machine` variables, but that doesn't change any of the facts mentioned above. The method you call is still from the superclass method.

Comment: Superb. This explains it.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's worth thinking of this in OO terms and not just as mechanics of constructors - this will help your coding more in the long term.

A simple way of thinking about the `extends` relationship is as is-a. In other words your code is saying that a `Camera` is a `Machine`. So anything that is true for a `Machine` is true for a `Camera` and you can always use a `Camera` anytime a `Machine` is required.

In your case you've said a `Machine` increments `id`. And you've said that `Camera`, as well as doing everything that a `Machine` does (because it is a `Machine`), increments `id`. So naturally this means two increments, once as a `Machine` and once as as `Camera`.

Both constructors set their id and then increment. Your `main` method creates a machine and three cameras. So ids will be:

machine id = 1
+1, id = 2
camera id = 2
+2, id = 4
camera id = 4
+2, id = 6
camera id = 6

Hence the output 1, 2, 4, 6

Comment: Yes I get it. But the thing is when I create a Camera object Camera cam = new Camera() it does not get incremented by 2.

Comment: Yes it does. It's incrementing by 2 *after* setting its own id. The next Camera object has an id 2 larger than the previous one.

Comment: @IshanBhatt just to be perfectly clear about this: it makes *no* difference to the behaviour of the constructor whether the new `Camera` is assigned to a `Machine` or `Camera` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `Camera` constructor also calls the `Machine` constructor. So every time you create a `Camera` object, you increment `id` by 2 – once in `Machine()` and then in `Camera()`. Maybe it is easier to understand if you add some output in the `Machine` and `Camera` constructors.

```
Camera() {
    // the Machine() constructor will be called and executed HERE
    this.mach_id = id;
    id++;
}
```

Comment: Ok. But what I fail to understand is when I am creating a Camera Object it is not incremented by two. i.e, when I created Camera cam = new Camera() it was only incremented by one. So when I am creating a Machine object using new Camera() I am actually calling the Camera constructor only. So in this case why does it increment by 2. I know I might be sounding naive but I am new to OOPs so please bear with me. Thanks –  Ishan Bhatt

Comment: @IshanBhatt I'll explain in my answer

Comment: What object you create depends on the constructor you call (i. e. the right side of the = operator). If you call the `Camera()` constructor, you *always* create a `Camera` object. The left side of the = operator is only the way to store the object. So if you use `Machine machine = new Camera()`, you create a `Camera` object but store it as a `Machine` which it obviously is.

Answer (score 0):

As Robin said it's all about `inheritance` concept not `polymorphism`

In Java, constructor of base class with no argument gets automatically called in derived class constructor. which make alot of sense,

if `Human` class has a `walk` method

and you make an instance from class `Student s = new Student()`

which inherits from `Human` if the constructor of `Human` not called then the object `s` cant call method walk which not initialized in memory

so the super constructor called before derived class constructor.